# Yii object instance method access

Tags: object, methods, yii, instance, overriding

This should be a very basic question for Yii coders, but I am not understanding the OOP relation here…

In my /protected/models/User.php I have a function like this…

```
public function encrypt($param)
{
...
}
```

For the User Authentication i.e., in the Class “class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity”
I have the Authenticate function like this…

```
public function authenticate()
{
$user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$this->username));
...
...
...
if($user->password !== $user->encrypt($this->password))
```

How is this possible?
encrypt is a method within User Class. Then it should be accessed in the following way…

```
$user = new User;
$user->encrypt();
```

But in the above code, $user is already accessing the static method model and then finds the record. So, how can we use $user as an object or instance.

Can anybody clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

`User::model()->findByAttributes` returns an instance of model (or null if nothing found) which you're correctly assigning to `$user` variable. Afterwards, you can call `encrypt()` or any other non-static method on `$user` just fine.

**EDIT:**

`User::model()` (or `MyModel::model()` in general) is a static method which returns instance of AR class which, among other things, can be used to perform `find*` calls. It **does not represent** any model inside database.

Actually, all `find*` methods should have been static (like `User::findBy`), but since Yii can't use PHP 5.3 features like LSB, it's impossible to implement it that way. So Yii developers ended up with `CActiveRecord::model()` method which acts like a static instance of a model.

Comment: if User::model()->find* returns instance, than what is this User::model(); model() is already a method within User class.

Comment: Okay! Then, I should be able to call the encrypt() method in this way    $user = new User;
$user->encrypt(); Is it correct.

Comment: @user2554706 Well, yes, nothing prevents you from doing that way. However, I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted in question

Answer (score 0):

Lets understand both the statements

```
 $user= User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$this->username));
```

Lets first understand **findByAttributes()**
This is defined in the **CActiveRecord class**,
which all database models should extend. In theory, you could create an instance of
the class and then use that instance’s method:

```
$model = new Page;
$model = $model->findByPk($id);
```

That would work, but it’s a bit verbose, redundant, and illogical. **The alternative is
to use a static class instance**. A static class instance is a more advanced OOP concept.
Now **User::model()**
If you will look into your User.php you will find a function like

```
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
            {
                    return parent::model($className);
            }
```

So what does **User::model()** does?
Here model() is a static method and here it represents **model() method of User class** .
So basically **User::model()** returns a **User class object.**
Hence when you execute this statement

```
$user= User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$this->username));
```

Then in turn you get a **User class object in the form of $user**.
And this is the reason that you can access `encrypt()` method like `$user->encrypt()`

**Source:-** Larry Ulman's Yii Book

Comment: lines into this answer are copied as it is from Yii book.